# Why is JavaScript function not returning anything if the return block is inside an if statement?

Tags: javascript

I have the following two functions that should be doing the same thing.  The first function `getProductIndex(id)` returns 2.  The second function `getProductIndex2(id)` returns undefined.  The only difference is the placement of the return statement.  Why is the function returning `undefined` if the return statement is inside the `if` statement?

```
function getProductIndex(id) {
  let num = "";
  products.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (item["productId"] === id) {
      num = index;
    }
  })
  return num;
}

function getProductIndex2(id) {
  products.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (item["productId"] === id) {
      return index;
    }
  })
}

console.log(getProductIndex(102));
console.log(getProductIndex2(102));
```

returns (2 is the correct index, FYI):

```
(base) j@joshs-mbp-2 javascript % node practice.js
2
undefined
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't use or return anything. use `.find` or `findIndex`

Comment: You're not returning anything in the function `getProductIndex2`, you're returning in the callback function you pass to `forEach`

Comment: @MichaelLiu i did not flag this as a dupe

Comment: @Lennholm got it.  So how would I get the value back with the ```getProductIndex2``` approach?

Comment: there is absolutely no way to get the value with `getProductIndex2` approach - you would have to rewrite it (i.e. use a *different* approach) using `.findIndex` as suggested in the first comment

Comment: @jpanknin As long as you're using `forEach` it won't work because `forEach` ignores any returned value and doesn't return anything to the caller. So, as others have pointed out, use `findIndex`, which does return a result to the caller. If you want to use `forEach` you have to go with your first approach but `findIndex` is better since it exists for this exact purpose.